# onBeforeAction Hooks of Iron router are played before and after onData Hooks, why?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm using iron-router in my apps, but whereas i'm trying to use Blaze hooks systems, i've seen some problem on routing. 
I thought that "before" hooks was called only once before action method. But in fact, It's called twice, one before onData, and one after onData... All before hooks are played each time.

Why ?

a sample app is available here https://github.com/Rebolon/meteor-sample-simpleVote/tree/bug/routing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs

> onBeforeAction
>   runs before the action function (possibly many times if reactivity is involved).

This means it runs once when the page loads, and again if there is any reactive variable in it. So if your `onBeforeAction` contains a reactive variable, and it changes, then it will run again.

So if you have subscriptions or something that you do in there it will run again. Is is likely that you may be using the same type of reactive component in your `data` method. This is why you find it runs multiple times.

Comment: argh :-) i've just thought at this yesterday. So i have to manage my session vars via Router, mainly.